# Angular 4 template binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

**AppComponent**

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        application: Application = new Application();
        pageTitle: string;
        constructor() {

            this.pageTitle = "{{application.businessName}} has been Approved";
            this.application.businessName = 'Test';
        }

    }
```

**AppComponent Html**

```
<h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
```

Results that I need

**Test has been Approved**

Comment: what is class `Application`? what was `businessName` before you assign `Test` to it?

Comment: for this example application class has one property called businessname

Comment: You didn't post enough information, for example: where's your Component Decorator details? What's the actual result you got? Please edit your question

Comment: updated the question

Comment: what is your query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the heading tag `<h1>` to update if the `Application` property changes.  The curly braces are used for templating meaning they're meant for your `html` pages and not within the `Component`.

What you can do is build the title in the template.

#### Option 1

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    application: Application = new Application();

    constructor() {
        this.application.businessName = 'Test';
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{application.businessName}} has been approved</h1>
```

#### Option 2

Or you could store the fragment of the title inside the `Component`

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    application: Application = new Application();
    pageTitleSuffix: string = "has been approved";
    constructor() {
        this.application.businessName = 'Test';
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{application.businessName}} {{pageTitleSuffix}}</h1>
```